# How to Check / Fix Broken Background Transfers - WP7

Tags: silverlight, download, windows-phone-7.1, digital-signature, progressive-download

I am developing an application which provides video download feature using Background Transfer.

Some times it says download is completed but on loading it in MediaLauncher it says can't play this file immediately or after playing it for partial period. it is my understanding that file is broken.

is there any solution to verify after downloading that file while server do not providing any hashing technique (digital signatures) so that i can check after download if the file is good to play or not and moreover if there is any fixing technique.

I haven't checked but I think server provides partial download (pause / resume).

Thanks